# CakePHP Checkbox Not Checked Using Form Helper

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.6

This is the process I've used to try and use the CakePHP Form Helper.  The examples are a mix of my own and ones I've found and definitely don't work.  Each example is running off the same data, which is set and should produce a checked checkbox, but using the Form Helper it definitely is working like I'd expect.

**This Works**

This does work, but I want to use the CakePHP form helper

```
<input type="checkbox" name="value" <?php if(($this->data[ $alias ])){echo "checked";}?>>
```

**But This Does Not Work**

```
<?php 
echo $this->Form->checkbox('value', [
    'checked' => ($this->data[ $alias ]) ? true : false
]); 
?>
```

**Does Not Work**

Apparently this does work for some people since I found this as a solution for many, but it definitely doesn't make the checkbox checked.

```
<?php 
$checked = if($this->data['alias']) ? true : false;
echo $this->Form->checkbox('value', ['checked' => $checked]); 
?>
```

**Does Work**

For whatever reason this does work, but isn't very useful so I did the next best thing in the following example.

```
<?php 
echo $this->Form->checkbox('value', ['checked']); 
?>
```

**But Then This Does Not Work???**

Though the example above does work this doesn't...

```
<?php 
$options = [];

if($this->data[ $alias ]) {
    array_push($options, 'checked');
    // $options = ['checked']; // this didn't work either
}

echo $this->Form->checkbox('value', $options); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it's stupid that I didn't try this earlier, but for those that have the same issue and pigeon hole themselves this requires you don't use booleans, has to be 'true' and 'false'.

**Solution That Works**

```
 <?php echo $this->Form->checkbox('value', [
        'checked' => ($this->data[ $alias ]) ? 'true' : 'false'
    ]); ?>
```

Comment: You should be passing down the data from the controller, and there in the controller set your default data and/or pass down the request data.
Your view should just contain $this->Form->checkbox('fieldname'). No need for anything else, see [this](http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/23/working-with-forms/).